# Active checkbox changes table background color except for a cell

Tags: html, css, checkbox

When the checkbox is inactive the table doesn't change, once the checkbox is clicked all the cells background color becomes yellow except for the middle one that becomes red.
[That's the result I need to reach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzJb4.png)

```css
label {
      -webkit-appearance: button;
      -moz-appearance: button;
      appearance: button;
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin:5px;
    }

    #checkbox_id:checked + table {
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    /*Table styles*/
    .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
    .tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
      overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
    .tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
      font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
    .tg .tg-0lax{text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Check6</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="checkbox_id">CLICCA</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_id">
    <table class="tg">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
    <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
    <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td id="red"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks already for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to your CSS:

```css
#checkbox_id:checked+table #red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here is a code snippet:

```css
label {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

#checkbox_id:checked+table {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#checkbox_id:checked+table #red {
  background-color: red;
}


/*Table styles*/

.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.tg th {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.tg .tg-0lax {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Check6</title>
</head>

<body>
  <label for="checkbox_id">CLICCA</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_id">
  <table class="tg">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
        <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
        <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
        <td id="red"></td>
        <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
        <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
        <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a function that get if Checkbox is checked and give the id "red" a color

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("checkbox_id");
  var red = document.getElementById("red");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    red.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else {
     red.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  }
}
```

```css
label {
      -webkit-appearance: button;
      -moz-appearance: button;
      appearance: button;
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin:5px;
    }

    #checkbox_id:checked + table {
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    /*Table styles*/
    .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
    .tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
      overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
    .tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
      font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
    .tg .tg-0lax{text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Check6</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="checkbox_id">CLICCA</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_id" onClick="myFunction()">
    <table class="tg">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
    <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
    <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td id="red"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or you can just use CSS like Mr.Run_Script showed you

Answer (score 0):

If your table is always the same HTML structure, you can select via :nth-child() any element inside the HTML tree.

for instance :  `#checkbox_id:checked + table  tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)`

```css
label {
      -webkit-appearance: button;
      -moz-appearance: button;
      appearance: button;
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin:5px;
    }

    #checkbox_id:checked + table {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    #checkbox_id:checked + table  tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) {
      background-color: red;
    }

    /*Table styles*/
    .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
    .tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
      overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
    .tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
      font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
    .tg .tg-0lax{text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Check6</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="checkbox_id">CLICCA</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_id">
    <table class="tg">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
    <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
    <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td id="red"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child
>
> The `:nth-child()` CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on their position in a group of siblings.

---

other option, select cells with a class and overwrite bg color

```
 #checkbox_id:checked + table  td {
      background-color: red;
    }
    #checkbox_id:checked + table  [class]{
      background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```css
label {
      -webkit-appearance: button;
      -moz-appearance: button;
      appearance: button;
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin:5px;
    }

    #checkbox_id:checked + table  td {
      background-color: red;
    }
    #checkbox_id:checked + table  [class]{
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    /*Table styles*/
    .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
    .tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
      overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
    .tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
      font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
    .tg .tg-0lax{text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Check6</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="checkbox_id">CLICCA</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_id">
    <table class="tg">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
    <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
    <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td id="red"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```